Filament: TextInput select field
In filament 3, how to make the TextInput so that when user click on it, it will select all the value in the input field?
The behavior will be similar like input.select()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select

Please read How do I ask a good question and edit your question accordingly.

@geertjanknapen Thanks for your comment. The question is improved.

Is it though? You changes some grammar and added a link. We need to see code of wht  you've tried and did not work, error messages you are getting. We can't do anything with the question as it currently stands. Please actually read how do I ask a good question.

TextInput::make('categories')
->extraInputAttributes(['onClick' => 'this.select();'])

Add extraInputAttributes attribute to your TextInput.
For more please follow https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/getting-started#adding-extra-html-attributes
